# Execute external program from Java

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I am trying to execute a program from the Java code. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    try {
      String line;
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
          "/bin/bash -c ls > OutputFileNames.txt");
      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }
      input.close();
    } catch (Exception err) {
      err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My OS is Mac OS X 10.6.

If I remove the `"> OutputFileNames.txt"` from the `getRuntime().exec()` method, all the file names are printed on the console just fine. But I need it to be printed to a file.

Also, if I change the command to:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "cmd \c dir > OutputFileNames.txt");
```

and run it on Windows, it  runs  and prints the results in the file perfectly fine too.

I have read the other posts for executing another application from Java but none seemed to relate to my problem.

I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks,

Comment: If the only thing you want to do is list the files in a directory, then there's no reason to do this by external program - you can just use `File.listFiles()` and write the result to a file yourself. That will work on any OS and doesn't need code specific to Mac OS X or Windows.

Comment: That's just a basic thing I am trying. Eventually what I want to do is run an external program called and print the output of that program in a file, then parse the file from Java to do other useful stuff.

Comment: Have you tried using .exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash",  "-c",  "ls > OutputFileNames.txt"}); Does it also fail?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Anton. That thing worked. I am sorry to ask a silly question but I am naive to developing in mac environment. 
Now, there is another problem I am having,
The application I want to run on the terminal starts its own little program and prints to itself and probably not the terminal. Because I cannot read anything from the console when I execute it. But, when I actually go to terminal and run the program I can see the output there.
So, what I am trying to do is spit all the output in a file and read that instead. But again, the file created by the java code is empty.

Comment: why have you asked the same question twice, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875085/execute-external-program-from-java

Comment: it is not the same... there is a slight difference. I just wanted to be clear of what I want that's why I put up a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the redirection to work as written, you need to do this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
      new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "ls > OutputFileNames.txt"});
```

The problem you were running into is the simple-minded way that that `Runtime.exec(String)` splits a command line into arguments.

If you were to run that command (as is) at a shell prompt, you would have had to have entered it as:

```
$ /bin/bash -c "ls > OutputFileNames.txt"
```

because the "-c" option for "bash" requires the command line for the spawned shell as a single shell argument.  But if you were to put the naked quotes into the Java String, the `Runtime.exec(String)` method still get the splitting wrong.  The only solution is to provide the command arguments as an array.

Comment: the javadoc states that the command line is split:  "The command argument is parsed into tokens and then executed as a command in a separate process. The token parsing is done by a StringTokenizer...". See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29

     new StringTokenizer(command)

Comment: @mdma - and that of course is the problem.  StringTokenizer does not understand quoted strings.

Comment: Ok, I see your edit, that you've quoted the command to bash. I didn't notice the original command line was wrong.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. That thing worked. I am sorry to ask a silly question but I am naive to developing in mac environment. Now, there is another problem I am having, The application I want to run on the terminal starts its own little program and prints to itself and probably not the terminal. Because I cannot read anything from the console when I execute it. But, when I actually go to terminal and run the program I can see the output there. So, what I am trying to do is spit all the output in a file and read that instead. But again, the file created by the java code is empty.

Comment: @Saurabh please ask a separate Question.  And please see if you can make it easier to understand.

Comment: @Saurabh Please see my answer. You cannot redirect to a file and read the process output from java at the same time.

Comment: @Stephen, here is the question again:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875085/execute-external-program-from-java

Let me know if it is still not clear.
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to look at.

- check which directory your program is running in (by running `pwd` the same way), then check to ensure you have permissions to write to that directory.
- see if that file `OutputFileNames.txt` already exists (and check permissions).
- if the file does exist, delete it and re-run to see if it gets re-created, and look at the contents if it does.
- try using the command `"/bin/bash -c 'ls > OutputFileNames.txt'"` - it may be that the `bash` output is *not* the same as the `ls` output (in your example the redirection could be applying to `bash` rather than `ls`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is happening because standard output of the process is being directed to the file, so the java `Process` cannot collect the output.

If you want the output written to a file, and be available for reading in java, then you have two options:

1. Keep the redirect in place, and then read the listing from the OutputFile.txt in java, e.g. using `new FileReader("OutputFile.txt")`. Note that `exec()` is asynchronous, and can return before the process has finished writing to file, so you will need to wait for the Process to exit, by using `Process.waitFor()`.
2. Remove the redirect, and read the listing directly into java (as you are doing.) You can then write this listing out to a file using `FileWriter`.

The bottom line is that you can't use both redirect and read the output from the Process at the same time - it's one or the other.

EDIT: Your comments indicate that 1) is the preferred approach. This will write the output to a file (using the OS shell) which you then read in from java when the process exits.