# Output the result of a bash script

Tags: java, linux

If for example I chose to run a bash script that would output (echo) the time e.g. `CheckDate.sh`. How could I run this from Java and then print the result of the bash script (the date) in my Java program?

Comment: Take a look at another question similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875085/execute-external-program-from-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code.

```
String result = null;
try {
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();                    

    Process p = r.exec("example.bat");

    BufferedReader in =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        result += inputLine;
    }
    in.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to assign your script execution in a Process object and retrieve the script ouput from its inputstream.

```
try {
    // Execute command
    String command = "ls";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    // Get the input stream and read from it
    InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        process((char)c);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Exception encountered", e);
}
```

Another way would be to make your bash scripts write its output in a file and then read this file back from Java.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The `java.lang.Process` class is intended for such purposes. You run an external process in Java either using the (simpler) `java.lang.Runtime.exec` function, or the (more complex) `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` class. Both give you, in the end, an instance of said `java.lang.Process`, whose `getInputStream` method you can call to get a stream from which you can read its output.

See the Javadoc for more information.