# How to show only the result when running Linux command in Java?

Tags: java, linux, jsch

I am using JSch to run some command in remote Linux box.

```
session = jsch.getSession(user, "host", 1222);
...
Channel shellChannel = session.openChannel("shell");
OutputStream ops = shellChannel.getOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);

ps.println("pwd");
InputStream in = shellChannel.getInputStream();
...
//print the char stream from 'in' using something similar to 
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126142/output-the-result-of-a-bash-script#
```

However, the printout of the result from `inputStream` contains everything, including user prompt, my original command (`pwd` in this case), and the result `/u02/app2/bbisit`:

```
bbisit@sdvdbres016$ 
bbisit@sdvdbres016$ pwd
/u02/app2/bbisit
```

But all I really want is the real output of the command, i.e. `/u02/app2/bbisit`.

Is there a way to get only the actual result of the command, but not the other garbage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "exec" channel, not the "shell" channel.

The "exec" channel is intended for automating command execution. The "shell" channel is intended for implementing an interactive shell.

See http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html