# Run a php script from a java class

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Execute external program from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874591/execute-external-program-from-java)

Is it possible to Run a php script from a java class. My project is a struts2 frame work web application. Its purely a java webapp We use a php script to run some daily cron jobs. It was written in php by an ex-employee. Is there a way to run the php script from the javaclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're essentially running a command line script, you could use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`.  Here's a page with a plethora of examples: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html.

If the PHP script is externalized as a web page, you could use Java's `URLConnection` to call the page so it runs.  Documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html