# Execute php from java program

Tags: java, php, macos, bash, shell

Here is my code:

```
String cmd = "bash -c \"php /Users/phyrrus9/Projects/java-web/test.php | say\"";
System.out.println("Executing: " + cmd);
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);
```

Yet, it is never executed. I can run that command from a shell and it works fine.
Here is the contents of test.php

```
<?php
     echo hello;
?>
```

Comment: `echo hello;` should be `echo "hello";`.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614995/calling-php-from-java

Comment: @Jlewis071 - that question is itself closed as a duplicate, linked to a question that is closed as "not a real question"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Runtime.exec()` is not a shell or a command interpreter, and is not treating your command the way you think it is.
The single-String argument version of exec() does a simple brain-dead split on spaces, so your quotes and escaped quotes are meaningless; they are never making it to bash in the way you think.

Always *always* use one of the execs that take a [`String[] cmdarray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[]%29)

Your args in this case are

```
"bash"
"-c"
"\"php /Users/phyrrus9/Projects/java-web/test.php | say\""
```

That is, you are running `bash` -- the first arg you are giving it is `-c` and the second arg is the string.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2874670/17300) to the more general question of how to [Execute external program from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874591/).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run it from a Process or Runtime class since PHP is a server side scripting which means it needs a server for it to run.

You need to use the HTTPDefaultClient class.

Take a look at this [site](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) it might help you.

Comment: Java is running on the server. PHP is running on the server.

Comment: Yeah but different servers.