# How can I open/execute an external file from within java?

Tags: java, swing

I have searched online and couldn't find a straight answer. I know how to read a file into java to be read or manipulated or even how to delete a file but I don't know how to execute an external file (stored on the user's system).

For instance if I had a list of books and their locations on the user's system. I'd like when the user clicks on a particular button then a pdf or document in a particular location is opened up in the relevant software e.g. adobe document reader or word etc.

How do I do this?

Comment: You mean that you are using a kind of FileChooser and when the user select the file you want to open it? `Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);` this may help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute external program in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991007/execute-external-program-in-java)

Comment: @dev_feed, I think he doesn't want to execute a file but open using default associate program (such as described in Desktop.open() method). But, sometimes...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004150/desktop-api-is-not-supported-on-the-current-platform.

Comment: @rdllopes my mistake, I read the title and whole first paragraph as a duplicate. hopefully someone with a better understanding of the question will edit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute external program from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874591/execute-external-program-from-java)

Comment: @james-kingsbery, I think this title is confusing people. Please, reconsider your title edition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Desktop class.

> the Desktop API (java.awt.Desktop) API, which allows Java applications
>   to interact with default applications associated with specific file
>   types on the host platform.

Read more here [How to integrate with the desktop class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)

Comment: @mikemil yes and also it's platform dependant that's why you have to use `isDesktopSupported()` as oracle tutorial says.